# Extract 1 Data Element from XMLDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have the following XML structure in a C# XMLDocument.

```
<result>
 <contact id="824" date="1404297626" dlm="1404297626" score="0.00" purl="" bulk_mail="1">
  <Group_Tag name="Contact Information">
   <field name="First Name">forename</field>
   <field name="Last Name">surname</field>
  </Group_Tag>
 </contact>
</result>
```

I'm looking to extract only the contact's id into a variable. How can I do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that code

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Xml.txt");
var res = doc.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("contact")).FirstOrDefault();
string ContactID = res.Attribute("id").Value;

MessageBox.Show("Your contact ID = "+ ContactID);
```

Or You can just use :

```
var res = (from x in doc.Descendants("contact")
           select x.Attribute("id").Value).FirstOrDefault();

MessageBox.Show("Your contact ID = "+ res.ToString());
```

Output

```
Your contact ID = 824
```

Comment: what are you using in the first code ? is it something different than linq ?

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward with a bit of LINQ:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var value = (from n in doc.Descendants("contact")
              select n.Attribute("id").Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

This assumes that the only element in the XML is the one you've shown. If you have more than one element you might consider using `FirstOrDefault();` instead.

Comment: nice and clean, just a note @Adam92: if it is known that there will be only one contact you can also make it more concise with doc.Root.Element("contact").Attribute("id").Value